# Absense of standardized naming convention in the C++ "standard"

Tags: c++, stl, naming-conventions, standards, std

Is it just me or is the "standard" C++ library totally absent of uniformity when it comes to naming conventions?

There are the underscore_identifiers, then there are many undecoratedidentifiers, then there are some capitalized like `std::ios_base::Init`, then there are the STL classes all in lowercase, as well as other oddities.

How can this mess of naming conventions even be classified as standard, it is a logical paradox...

Why isn't a naming convention enforced?

Comment: It is mostly uniform (lower case with underscore delimiters); there are just a few parts inherited from pre-standard libraries that used other conventions. Presumably, no-one was quite anal enough to insist that these be bludgeoned into conformity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can this mess of naming conventions even be classified as standard[?]

Standard-ness is orthogonal to neatness, unfortunately.

> Why isn't a naming convention enforced?

Well, you've obviously never been on a committee!

Comment: So, the purpose of a committee is to be counter-productive? Makes sense, if I am to be completely honest.

Comment: @ddriver: They don't set out to do it but, well, we all know where camels came from.

Comment: @ddriver: Anyway, if you think that the committee hasn't "produced" anything then you should take a look at the corpus of papers and standards that form its output.

Comment: @ddriver Yes, they could have come up with a naming convention when they started, but they didn't. The original standard library was made up of various libraries developed by various people and it continues to evolve in the same way. There is, in general, a de facto naming convention, but it's far too late to change the older library content to match. In terms of productiveness, you only need to [look at this year's mailings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/) to realise how much development happens in a short period of time.

Comment: Well, in my mind a committee should ensure to keep things objective and balanced. "To each his own" isn't very objective, it is very subjective and far from balanced. I guess the reason many committee members are there to begin with is to try and push the development in a direction that is convenient to the third party they represent. But this is pretty much an internal power struggle and is far from constructive. I don't say the C++ standard committee is overall nonconstructive - obliviously they generate output.. but still.

Comment: @ddriver: As the number of components in a decision-making group tends to infinity, the chance of agreeing on anything at all tends to zero. And, in fact, the median of the resulting curve is fairly low - I'd say around 50 or so. Just look at the US Congress, or UK HM Parliament.

Comment: Sheesh, all the trite wisdom about how committees work, instead of **actual** analysis of **real** data. To those of us who have spent **years** working on the standard, this kind of cheap shot is insulting. Yes, there are a handful of inconsistencies, partly because of past practice and partly because of the sheer size of the standard. If you think there's significant improvement to be made, **join** the committee, **participate** in standardization, and **propose** fixes.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I do participate (indirectly). I'm not proposing any changes. And I'm not taking any cheap shots. I am, in fact, _defending_ the committee.

Comment: I think he was referring to me. However, I don't think more people joining in will result in anything good, considering the problem is there are too much people in already.